# INSERT INTO ... SELECT: Operand should contain 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join, operand

I haven't been playing with SQL for a while and I lost the hang of it. I have this query

```
INSERT INTO company_reports (
        company_id, quarter, leftover, produced,
        sold, price, cost, income,
        expenses, profit, dividends
    ) SELECT 
        ct.id, 5, c.leftover, ct.produced, 
        ct.sold, c.price, c.cost, ct.sold*c.price, 
        ct.produced*c.cost, 
        ct.sold*c.price-ct.produced*c.cost, 
        (ct.produced*c.cost, ct.sold*c.price-ct.produced*c.cost) * c.dividends
        FROM companies_tmp ct 
        INNER JOIN companies c 
            ON ct.id = c.id;
```

And for some reason, my MySQL tells me this

```
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

I have no idea what ´operand´ means in this context.

There is also this:
[image: ?]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you put the operations that you are performing in the select query inside brackets and check?

Comment: What is `(ct.produced*c.cost, ct.sold*c.price-ct.produced*c.cost)` supposed to mean? The comma doesn't seem to make sense in the context.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Dammit, well, that changes it all.

Comment: What are you trying to do there? (in the line joachim mentioned)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Thank you, didn't notice that bracket. Solved now.